# Finding xmlns with xsl/xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to obtain a list of information for the root element of an xml document using a transformation. The pieces I can't figure out are:

How do I obtain the default namespace url?

How can I obtain a list of every xmlns prefix and its related url?

Here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/example.xsl"?>
<foo:mytag xmlns="http://default.example.com/" 
           xmlns:foo="http://foo.example.com/" 
           xmlns:bar="http://bar.example.com">
</foo:mytag>
```

And here is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output
     doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
     doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
     encoding="UTF-8"
     indent="yes"
     method="xml"
     omit-xml-declaration="no"
     version="1.0" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                default namespace - <b>???</b><br />
                full tag name - <b><xsl:value-of select="name(*)"/></b><br />
                xmlns for tag - <b><xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri(*)"/></b><br />
                tag prefix - <b>???</b><br />
                tag name - <b><xsl:value-of select="local-name(*)"/></b><br />
                List of xmlns - <br />
                ????
            </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template>
```

This transformation is being done in the browser. Basically what I'm expecting as a result:

```
default namespace - http://default.example.com/
full tag name - foo:mytag
xmlns for tag - http://foo.example.com/
tag prefix - foo
tag name - mytag
List of xmlns -
        - http://default.example.com/
    foo - http://foo.example.com/
    bar - http://bar.example.com/
```

Am I missing something obvious to fill in the missing data?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's more usual to want to know the namespace associated with a node, than to just want the list of namespace declarations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does approximately what you want. XSLT 1.0 - tested in XMLSpy

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            default namespace - <b><xsl:value-of select="*/namespace::*[not (name())]"/></b><br />
            full tag name - <b><xsl:value-of select="name(*)"/></b><br />
            xmlns for tag - <b><xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri(*)"/></b><br />
            tag prefix - <b><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(name(*),':')" /></b><br />
            tag name - <b><xsl:value-of select="local-name(*)"/></b><br />
            List of xmlns - <br />
            <xsl:for-each select="*/namespace::*">
               <xsl:if test="not (name() = 'xml')"><xsl:text>
                   </xsl:text>
                   <xsl:value-of select="name()" /><xsl:text> - </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="." /><br />
               </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```